# Electronjs : Rounded Menu Corners

Tags: menu, electron, desktop-application, menuitem

I'm building a **desktop app** using Electronjs + React.
after the setting up the topbar menu, when i expand any submenu, **the submenu corners are rounded**:

[image: rounded corners example]

The docs didn't mention anything about it.
how can i modify the border radius?

Comment: Which operating system are you on? I doubt this is something either Electron or React has an influence on.

Comment: Windows 11, do you think that the os might be the influence?

Comment: This appears to affect all Electron apps, and it specifically happens only on Windows 11, and not on Windows 10. (Tested VS Code with the "custom title bar" disabled, plus some others.) I don't think you have control over this when developing an app. But, if anyone knows a way to force the Windows 10 look on all Electron apps when running on Windows 11, I'd love to hear it.